# How to add user data upon account creation that can't be edited by the user?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I'm looking to store some user information in a Firebase realtime database when a user account is created, but that shouldn't be writable by the user later, and I can't seem to figure out how I should go about doing that. From what I understand when an account is created all data besides sign in specific data (facebook login, google login, email/password login) is stored "by the user" in that it's only written to places that the user has access to write to.

What I'm looking to do it write additional data on account creation that can't be later changed by the user, but it seems like the only way to write that data in the first place is for the user to have write access to it. How can I write data once on account creation that can't be later written to by the user?

Example:

Say I'm trying to store a phone number with the account, and my security rules look like this:

```
"rules":{
  ".read":false,
  ".write":false,
  "users":{
    "$user_id":{
      ".read": true,
      "writeable_data":{ //written to on account creation, can be changed later by user
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id",
        "name": {".validate":true}
      },
      "unchanging_data":{ //written to on account creation, shouldn't be later changed
        "phone_number": {".validate":"newData.isNumber() && newData.val().length() == 10"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that the phone_number field is written to when the account is created (assume it's given from whatever web form they fill out or something similar) but then can't be edited by the user again? Is there a way this can be done with Firebase database security rules or do I have to make a call to some separate server that has admin access and that confirms the data and does the write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. If you check to make sure there is not pre-existing data, updates (and deletes) will be prevented:

```
"unchanging_data": {
  "phone_number": {
    ".validate": "!data.exists() && newData.isNumber() && newData.val().length() == 10" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Weird that I had such a hard time finding it. Thanks!